# How can I in Oracle discover the average number of rows affected per transaction?

Tags: oracle, transaction

Our Oracle server is a big cluster of three very large individual instances. I want to try to understand the average number of rows per transaction. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: via audit trial you can monitor the database transaction and how many row hes been effected by X transaction

Comment: Could you elaborate on you mean exactly? "Modified" rows? By itself a number of rows is pretty meaningless in itself - some queries can return thousands of rows at essentially no cost, while some others might put an instance "on its knees" for hours and return nothing at all.

Comment: Modified rows - i.e.: DML statements - number of rows inserted, updated or deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly an answer to your question but amount of changes generated by the session can be found using such query.

```
select st.inst_id, trunc(st.value/(1024*1024)) as MB, ss.sid, ss.username,
  ss.osuser, ss.machine, ss.program, ss.logon_time
from gv$sesstat st, v$statname sn, gv$session ss
where st.statistic# = sn.STATISTIC# and sn.name = 'redo size'
  and st.inst_id = ss.inst_id and st.sid = ss.sid and ss.type != 'BACKGROUND'
order by 2 desc;
```

Number of rows changed correlates with amount of redo generated.

Comment: Number of blocks is useful, but does not relate directly to rows. This is an interesting answer however - thank you very much +1

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain the context a bit more, please?

**Do you mean the average number of rows a SQL query returns?**

This helps you to find out if an SQL query was executed well. An SQL query that returns 50 rows but does a *full table scan* over 10mil rows is not good. An SQL query that returns 8mil rows with a *index access* is not good either. So this helps you to find queries which can be optimized.

**Do you mean generated amount of undo?**

I think Mindaugas Riauba answered that already.

**Where else did you get this information from?**

Did you find it in an AWR or Statspack report?